# Using `line-seq` with `reader`, when is the file closed?

Tags: clojure, io, lazy-evaluation

I'm reading lines from a text file using `(line-seq (reader "input.txt"))`.  This collection is then passed around and used by my program.

I'm concerned that this may be bad style however, as I'm not deterministically closing the file.  I imagine that I can't use `(with-open (line-seq (reader "input.txt")))`, as the file stream will potentially get closed before I've traversed the entire sequence.

Should `lazy-seq` be avoided in conjunction with `reader` for files?  Is there a different pattern I should be using here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since this doesn't really have a clear answer (it's all mixed into comments on the first answer), here's the essence of it:

```
(with-open [r (reader "input.txt")]
  (doall (line-seq r)))
```

That will force the whole sequence of lines to be read and close the file. You can then pass the result of that whole expression around.

When dealing with large files, you may have memory problems (holding the whole sequence of lines in memory) and that's when it's a good idea to invert the program:

```
(with-open [r (reader "input.txt")]
  (doall (my-program (line-seq r))))
```

You may or may not need doall in that case, depending on what my-program returns and/or whether my-program consumes the sequence lazily or not.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the [clojure.contrib.duck-streams/read-lines](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/duck-streams-api.html#clojure.contrib.duck-streams/read-lines) is just what you are looking for. `read-lines` closes the file when there is no input and returns the sequence just like `line-seq`. Try to look at source code of `read-lines`.

Comment: clojure.contrib.duck-streams is deprecated: http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/#duck-streams

Comment: @pauldoo I didn't notice this. You're right, but functions `line-seq` and `read-line` use the same pattern to retrieve strings from the reader (by .readLine). Just look at them ([line-seq](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f86db9cc68773dd3e4a166c1ff7b81e4a98aa602/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2314), [read-line](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib/blob/aa3f018f65006c78b08703e7adef04b7f39e1542/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/duck_streams.clj#L236)), if you want laziness you could grab `read-line` into your source code.

Comment: @pauldoo As I can see another solution is not to use laziness and grab the whole content into a variable or just use .close on the reader. And you should use `with-open` like this `(with-open [r (reader "input.txt")] (make-smth-on-lines (line-seq r)))`.

Comment: Add a strategically placed `doall` around the `make-smth-on-lines` in case it returns a lazy sequence. Without the `doall` you'll run into trouble when the sequence is realised outside the `with-open` block, because the file is already closed.

Comment: It is good point, because I didn't even think to use sequence outside of the `with-open` block. I think io functions are intended to use within the `with-open` block.