# Clojure in Action, Ch 12 Data Analysis example, dependency issues

Tags: clojure, mapreduce, stack-trace, dependency-management, name-collision

I am working through the first edition of this book and while I enjoy it, some of the examples given seem out-dated. I would give up and find another book to learn from, but I am really interested in what the author is talking about and want to make the examples work for myself, so I am trying to update them as I go along.

The following code is a map/reduce approach to analyzing text that depends on clojure.contrib. I have tried changing the .split function to re-seq with #"\w+", used line-seq instead of read-lines, and changed the .toLowerCase to string/lower-case. I tried to follow my problems to the source code and read the docs thoroughly to learn that the read-lines function closes after you consume the entire sequence and that line-seq returns a lazy sequence of strings, implementing java.io.BufferedReader. The most helpful thing for my problem was [post about how to read files after clojure 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756909/in-clojure-1-3-how-to-read-and-write-a-file). Even still, I can't get it to work.

So here's my question: What dependencies and/or functions do I need to change in the following code to make it contemporary, reliable, idiomatic Clojure?

First namespace:

```
(ns chapter-data.word-count-1
  (:use clojure.contrib.io
        clojure.contrib.seq-utils))

(defn parse-line [line]
  (let [tokens (.split (.toLowerCase line) " ")]
    (map #(vector % 1) tokens)))

(defn combine [mapped]
  (->> (apply concat mapped)
       (group-by first)
       (map (fn [[k v]]
              {k (map second v)}))
       (apply merge-with conj)))

(defn map-reduce [mapper reducer args-seq]
  (->> (map mapper args-seq)
       (combine)
       (reducer)))

(defn sum [[k v]]
  {k (apply + v)})

(defn reduce-parsed-lines [collected-values]
  (apply merge (map sum collected-values)))

(defn word-frequency [filename]
  (map-reduce parse-line reduce-parsed-lines (read-lines filename)))
```

Second namespace:

```
(ns chapter-data.average-line-length
  (:use rabbit-x.data-anal
        clojure.contrib.io))

(def IGNORE "_")

(defn parse-line [line]
  (let [tokens (.split (.toLowerCase line) " ")]
    [[IGNORE (count tokens)]]))

(defn average [numbers]
  (/ (apply + numbers)
     (count numbers)))

(defn reducer [combined]
  (average (val (first combined))))

(defn average-line-length [filename]
  (map-reduce parse-line reducer (read-lines filename)))
```

But when I compile and run it in light table I get a bevy of errors:

1) In the word-count-1 namespace I get this when I try to reload the ns function after editing:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: spit already refers to: #'clojure.contrib.io/spit in namespace: chapter-data.word-count-1
```

2) In the average-line-length namespace I get similar name collision errors under the same circumstances:

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: parse-line already refers to: #'chapter-data.word-count-1/parse-line in namespace: chapter-data.average-line-length, compiling:(/Users/.../average-line-length.clj:7:1)
```

3) Oddly, when I quit and restart light table, copy and paste the code directly into the files (replacing what's there) and call instances of their top level functions the word-count-1 namespace runs fine, giving me the number of occurrences of certain words in the test.txt file but the average-line-length name-space gives me this:

```
"Warning: *default-encoding* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *default-encoding* or change the name. (clojure/contrib/io.clj:73)...
```

4) At this point when I call the `word-frequency` functions of the first namespace it returns `nil` instead of the number of word occurrences and when I call the `average-line-length` function of the second namespace it returns

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
            core.clj:1502 clojure.core/val
```

Comment: I would guess that the errors you're getting are related to LightTable. Maybe try adding `lighttable` to your tags on this question and see if somebody watching that tag will be able to offer some guidance? Also, try running your code from the command line with Leiningen and see if that makes any difference. These aren't the kinds of errors you would usually get from running Clojure code.

Comment: For the record, I use LightTable, but don't run into these problems, so if it is a LightTable thing, perhaps it could be fixed by changing some LT config settings, or by reinstalling it from scratch. That's a stab in the dark, though :)

Comment: Good point. I'll try it in another use and see if it keeps happening, and if not reinstall light table. Regarding outdated idioms/dependencies though, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I get the exact same errors but as warnings in the terminal leiningen repl, and emacs. Each mentions contrib.io or contrib.seq.utils, and if I change the code I get name collission errors, the same as above. I am pretty sure I need to swap out dependencies and use different functions. But which ones?

Comment: Extra info: I'm pretty sure that in Clojure 1.2 you could bind values to symbols dynamically without having to declare it, and that they were *earmuffed* by convention. In later versions, these conventions became requirements, following the philosophy that mutating code should be strongly typed. It is understandable that a 1.2 contrib library, which is not maintained to adhere to later requirements would not be changed to support dynamic binding under the hood. Also, a lot of the predefined symbols used in contrib were migrated to different namespaces, meaning that there probably is overlap.

Comment: OK, I think I figured out the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `clojure.contrib.io` and `clojure.contrib.seq-utils` are no longer updated, and in fact they may be conflicting with `clojure.core` functions like `spit`. I would recommend taking out those dependencies and seeing if you can do this using only core functions. `spit` should just work -- the error that you're getting is caused by `use`ing `clojure.contrib.io`, which contains its own `spit` function, which looks to be roughly equivalent; perhaps the current version in `clojure.core` is a "new and improved" version of `clojure.contrib.io/spit`.

Your problem with the `parse-line` function looks to be caused by the fact that you've defined two functions with the same name, in two different namespaces. The namespaces don't depend on one another, but you can still run into a conflict if you load both namespaces in a REPL. If you only need to use one at a time, try using one of them, and then when you want to use the other one, make sure you do a `(remove-ns name-of-first-ns)` first to free up the vars so there is no conflict. Alternatively, you could make `parse-line` a private function in each namespace, by changing `(defn parse-line ...` to `(defn- parse-line ...`.

EDIT: If you still need any functions that were in `clojure.contrib.io` or `clojure.contrib.seq-utils` that aren't available in `core` or elsewhere, you can always copy the source over into your namespace. See [clojure.contrib.io](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/io.clj) and [clojure.contrib.seq-utils](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/seq_utils.clj) on github.

Comment: This just about answers my question, but to put it more succinctly, I should remove both of the contrib libraries, put `(:import (java.io BufferedReader))` in the `chapter-data.word-count-1` namespace and copy the read-lines function directly from the clojure.contrib.io namespace to suit my needs. I did all of this and can attest to the fact that it works. I just have trouble believing that read-lines hasn't migrated to a new core function, maybe with a different name. I have looked at read-line, line-seq and so on, but just can't find our culprit!

Comment: I think `line-seq` should be able to do what you need... is it not working as expected?

Comment: Glossing the source, line-seq takes an instance of BufferedReader as an argument, and then returns a lazy seq, recursively reading each line in that reader, whereas read-lines opens the BufferedReader instance, taking a file as an argument, then reads each line into a lazy-seq before closing the reader. I'm not gonna lie, I don't really understand what either a reader/buffer/or buffered reader are more deeply than this single example. This question touches on the same thing we are dealing with here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613470/using-line-seq-with-reader-when-is-the-file-closed

Comment: Here is A discussion on a similar topic on the google clojure group: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/clojure/MkHB3SHrGZY