# How To Read Directory Of Files, Line by Line, Lazily in Clojure

Tags: clojure, io, seq

```
(->> "/Users/micahsmith/printio/gooten-import-ai/jupyter/data"
     File.
     file-seq
     (filter #(-> ^File % .getAbsolutePath (str-contains? ".json")))
     (mapcat (fn [^File file]
            (with-open [ rdr (io/reader file)]
              (line-seq rdr)))))
```

I'm trying to read a directory of json files line-by-line, lazily, so that i can perform an operation lazily on the data.

I keep getting `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` -- how can i consume this without closing the reader too early?

Comment: The answer here should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797629

Comment: Just to have it asked: those "json" files are readable line by line?  e.g. they are more like one json-object a line?

Answer (score 2):

The `with-open` function is designed to discourage you from doing this, because file handles and other operating system resources are the sort of thing you should handle carefully instead of lazily. You are intended to do all processing of the file contents within the dynamic scope of your `with-open`. So, instead of returning a lazy sequence, you should accept a function as an argument, and call that function on the lazy sequence while still within the scope of `with-open`. That function should of course not return another lazy sequence, but instead process its entire input before returning.

So the typical use for such a thing is like this:

```
(defn process-file [filename process]
  (with-open [f (io/reader filename)]
    (process (line-seq f))))
```

It's a little more complicated when you have a list of `with-open` sequences - you can't just call `process` once. One thing you could do is return a list of the results of calling `process` on each file:

```
(defn process-files [filenames process]
  (for [filename filenames]
    (with-open [f (io/reader filename)]
      (process (line-seq f)))))
```

Then if you need to do some global operation on that, you can `reduce` over the result of `process-files`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `with-open` calls `.close` when the program exits the scope it's enclosing, but all the lines haven't necessarily been read by that point.

My solution is probably an abusive abomination that should never have seen the light of day, but here's the idea: create a "`lazy-seq`" that just calls `.close`, and concatenate it to the end of the `line-seq` list:

```
(defn lazy-lines [^File file]
  (let [rdr (io/reader file)]
    (lazy-cat (line-seq rdr)
              (do (.close rdr)
                  nil)))) ; Explicit nil to indicate termination

(defn get-lines [^String path]
  (->> path
       (File.)
       (file-seq)
       (filter #(-> ^File % (.getAbsolutePath) (clojure.string/includes? ".json")))
       (mapcat lazy-lines)))
```

From my quick testing with files on my Desktop, it appears to work. If you add a `println` into the terminating `lazy-seq`, it prints as expected, so the file *is* being closed.

I'm hesitant to suggest this solution though as it relies on carrying out side effects inside of a lazy-list, which I've been conditioned to "feel wrong" for obvious reasons. The major downside of this method is that the file won't be closed unless the entire sequence is evaluated, and the file will stay open the entire time until the end is reached. Given the constraints though, I don't see how either of these problems could be avoided.

---

I realized I was using `lazy-cat` slightly wrong. I had an extra, unnecessary `lazy-seq` wrapper. It's fixed now. You could also just use something like

```
(apply concat (line-seq rdr)
              (lazy-seq (do (.close rdr)
                            nil))))))
```

Instead of `lazy-cat`.